# SELECT >>> OPTION >>> selected value

Tags: html, javascript

Как в Javascript обозначить переменную selected value (взять значение selected)? Короче, вот есть исходный код, что-то типа того. Вот как правильно писать этот код, чтобы ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ устанавливала своё значение из списка (из выбранного OPTION).

> `var ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ = document.getElementByName('ИМЯ SELECT').selected value`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если писать на чистом JS, то можно использовать такой код:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="selectId" onchange="change()">
    <option value="0">Select option</option>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
var select, value, text;

function change() {
    select = document.getElementById("selectId"); // Выбираем  select по id
    value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; // Значение value для выбранного option
    text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text; // Текстовое значение для выбранного option
    alert("Value: " + value + "\nТекст: " + text); // Вывод алерта для проверки значений
}
```

[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/s65n9b3z/)

---

Но можно это же написать на `jQuery`, мне этот вариант нравится больше:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="0">Select option</option>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>

<p>Value: <span id="value">0</span></p>
<p>Text: <span id="text">Select option</span></p>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectId").change(function() {
        $("#value").text($(this).val());
        $("#text").text($("#selectId option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

[Посмотреть пример на jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/s65n9b3z/1/)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Мне именно это и нужно! Согласен с Вами, что на Jquery вариант получше.