# Смена изображения при select option

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

У меня есть `option`, в котором я выбираю опцию, к которой привязана та или иная картинка (миниатюра). Также, на сайте имеется другое изображение (большой формат). Так вот - как поменять это изображение на другое, если я выбрал опцию, к которой привязана картинка, на которую нужно сменить? Вот мой нынешний кусочек кода:

```
$('#570df42e93295').msDropDown({
    byJson:{data:ddData},
    on:{
        change: function( data, ui ) {
            var val = data.value;
            ui.data( 'value', val );
            bt_quote_total( $( ui ).closest( '.btQuoteBooking' ) );
            bt_paypal_items( $( ui ).closest( '.btQuoteBooking' ) );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: В следующий раз используете кнопку `{}`, когда вставляете код.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я использовал ее, и к сожалению получился такой вид (,

Comment: Просто смотрите, чтобы каждая строка кода начиналась с четырёх пробелов. Их можно и самому поставить, если что ;)

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте нормальный ответ, я в js почти ничего не понимаю. Все что мне нужно - это при выборе опции получить название картинки, и изменить картинку в другом блоке

Comment: выглядит так, будто этот код вырван из контекста и к делу не относится. если надо изменить картинку в зависимости от значения выбранной опции, то ищите что-то типа [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/386186/select-option-selected-value) - считываете значение option и меняете в зависимости от него какую-то картинку в каком-то блоке. можете для этого использовать switch

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Пример реализации с отдельным `json` объектом изображений

```
var images_store = {
 'foo': 'http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264.3-hp2x.gif',
 'bar': 'http://newinform.com/uploads/posts/2016-02/1455899769_yahoo-logo.jpg',
 'baz': 'http://bits.media/images/news/050815/050815_Microsoft-bitcoin-v-bing_1.jpg',
}
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
      $('img').attr('src', images_store[$(this).val()]);
  });
});
```

В значениях объекта можно хранить ссылку на оригинальное изображение и миниатюру.

```
var images_store = {
   'foo': {
       'full': 'image_path_http',
       'thumb': 'image_path_http'
    }
}
```

Остается поправить выборку

```
$('img').attr('src', images_store[$(this).val()]['full']);
```

Демо:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqzyyw